# Question about Yfinance, IndexError, and Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, yfinance

I am trying to use linear regression using data pulled from yfinance to predict future stock prices, but I am having trouble using linear regression after transposing my data's shape.

Here I create a normalization function

```
def normalize_data(df):
    # df on input should contain only one column with the price data (plus dataframe index)
    min = df.min()
    max = df.max()
    x = df 
    
    # time series normalization part
    # y will be a column in a dataframe
    y = (x - min) / (max - min)
    
    return y
```

And another function to pull stock prices from Yfinance that calls the normalization function

```
def closing_price(ticker):
    #Asset = pd.DataFrame(yf.download(ticker, start=Start,end=End)['Adj Close'])   
    Asset = pd.DataFrame(yf.download(ticker, start='2022-07-13',end='2022-09-16')['Adj Close'])   
    Asset = normalize_data(Asset)
    return Asset.to_numpy()
```

I then pull 11 different stocks using the function

```
MRO= closing_price('MRO')
HES= closing_price('HES')
FANG= closing_price('FANG')
DVN= closing_price('DVN')
PXD= closing_price('PXD')
COP= closing_price('COP')
CVX= closing_price('CVX')
APA= closing_price('APA')
EOG= closing_price('EOG')
HAL= closing_price('HAL')
BLK = closing_price('BLK')
```

Which works so far
But when I try to merge the first 10 numpy arrays together,

```
X = np.array([MRO, HES, FANG, DVN, PXD, COP, CVS, APA, EOG, HAL])[:, :, 0]
X = np.transpose(X)
```

it gives me the error for the first line when I merge the numpy arrays

```
<ipython-input-53-a30faf3e4390>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
```

Comment: Are you sure `MRO` (for example) is just a plain float value?  Or is it some wrapper object?

Comment: I believe its an object, when I print MRO it returns a 2d numpy array

Comment: The "ragged" part means the subarrays are not all the same size/

Comment: As far as I am concerned, when you are finding the closing price of every stocks, not all the stocks have the same number of days. This will cause the array of every stock to be different size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the following as is suggested by your error message?

```
X = np.array([MRO, HES, FANG, DVN, PXD, COP, CVS, APA, EOG, HAL], dtype=float)[:, :, 0]
```

Alternatively, what are you trying to do with your data afterwards, run a linear regression? Does the data have to be an np array? Often working with data is a lot easier using `pandas.DataFrame`, and basically all machine learning libraries such as `sklearn` or `statsmodels` or any other you might want to use will have pandas support.

To create one big dataset out of these you could try the following:

```
data = pd.DataFrame() #creating empty dataframe
list_of_tickers = [MRO, HES, FANG, DVN, PXD, COP, CVS, APA, EOG, HAL, BLK]

for ticker in list_of_tickers:
    for column in ticker: #because each column will just be labelled "Adj. Close" and you can't name multiple columns the same way
        new_name = str(ticker) + "_" + str(column) #columns in data will then be named "MRO_Adj. Close", "HES_Adj. Close", etc
        ticker[new_name] = ticker[column]
        ticker = ticker.drop(column, axis=1) 
 
    data = pd.concat([data, ticker], axis=1)
```

Additionally, this neatly prevents problems that might arise from issues that different stock tickers have or lack different dates in their dataset, as was correctly pointed out by Kevin Choon Liang Yew in the comments [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73823123/question-about-yfinance-indexerror-and-numpy-arrays#comment130357503_73823123).